# redux-observable: Mapping to an action as soon as another was triggered at least once

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an SPA that is loading some global/shared data (let's call this APP_LOAD_OK) and page-specific data (DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK) from the server. I want to show a loading animation until both APP_LOAD_OK and DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK are dispatched.

Now I have a problem with expressing this in RxJS. What I need is to trigger an action after each DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK, as long as there had been **at least** one APP_LOAD_OK. Something like this:

```
action$
  .ofType(DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK)
  .waitUntil(action$.ofType(APP_LOAD_OK).first())
  .mapTo(...)
```

Does anybody know, how I can express it in valid RxJS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `withLatestFrom` since it will wait until both sources emit at least once before emitting. If you use the `DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK` as the primary source:

```
action$.ofType(DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK)
  .withLatestFrom(action$.ofType(APP_LOAD_OK) /*Optionally*/.take(1))
  .mapTo(/*...*/);
```

This allows you to keep emitting in the case that DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK fires more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid implementing a new operator, because I thought my RxJS knowledge was not good enough for that, but it turned out to be easier than I thought. I am keeping this open in case somebody has a nicer solution. Below you can find the code.

```
Observable.prototype.waitUntil = function(trigger) {
  const source = this;
  let buffer = [];
  let completed = false;

  return Observable.create(observer => {
    trigger.subscribe(
      undefined,
      undefined,
      () => {
        buffer.forEach(data => observer.next(data));
        buffer = undefined;
        completed = true;
      });

    source.subscribe(
      data => {
        if (completed) {
          observer.next(data);
        } else {
          buffer.push(data);
        }
      },
      observer.error.bind(observer),
      observer.complete.bind(observer)
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: There are a couple dangers in this implementation that you should be aware of: a) You are not cleaning up the subscription you create (x2), to be a good operator you should be returning the subscriptions you create in `create`, b) `buffer` and `completed` are created *per invocation* not *per subscription*, this is shared state which is no bueno for cold Observables (hint try subscribing to this stream more than once. You will likely see some strange behavior).

Comment: You are right, big thanks for clearing it up. :) Did not put that much thought into it, I was just glad that I finally have some solution. (I might edit it later when I have more time, or feel free to do so yourself, if you like)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive every DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK after the first APP_LOAD_OK You can simply use [skipUntil](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipUntil):

```
action$ .ofType(DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK)
  .skipUntil(action$.ofType(APP_LOAD_OK).Take(1))
  .mapTo(...)
```

This would only start emitting DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK actions after the first APP_LOAD_OK, all actions before are ignored.

Comment: I considered this solution too. The problem is that, initially (on page load), both async "tasks" are started at the same time, so they can finish in any order. This would mean that sometimes the loading animation would never finish (if DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK arrived first).

Comment: If you only require them both to emit once then you can use `Rx.Observable.zip(action$ .ofType(DASHBOARD_LOAD_OK),  action$.ofType(APP_LOAD_OK)).take(1).Map/**/)`